# Replacing multiples patterns in a text file

Tags: javascript

Code:

**en.txt:**

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

**es.txt:**

```
Linea 1
Linea 2
Linea 3
```

**html.text:**

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
<p>Line 3</p>
```

**index.js:**

```
fs.readFile('html.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  var result = []

  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }

  for (i = 0; i < esStrings.length; i++) { 
    var re = new RegExp(enStrings[i], "g")
    result = data.replace(re, esStrings[i])
  }

  console.log(result)
})
```

I'm using the lines in `en.txt` as patterns and the lines in `es.txt` as replacements. The content being replaced is in `html.txt`.
`enStrings` and `esStrings` are the array versions of `en.txt` and `es.txt`

The desired output is this:

```
<p>Linea 1</p>
<p>Linea 2</p>
<p>Linea 3</p>
```

but I'm getting this instead:

```
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
<p>Linea 3</p>
```

How can I modify the code so I get the first output?

Comment: i think it's because of multiple lines try like  `var re = new RegExp(enStrings[i], "gm")`